# Python: Extract Text from Script Tag using XPath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to use xpath to access the text inside the html below.

I've written this statement **response.xpath(//script/text())** to extact the text within the tag. For some reason I'm not seeing the data expected text.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
Method: response.xpath(//script/text())

<script>
digitalData={
                       page:{
                pageInfo:{
                    destinationURL:window.location.href,
                    error:'',
                    language:'en' ,
                    country:'US' ,
                    pageName:'tangelo2' ,
                    articlepubdate:'' ,
                    articleenddate:'' ,
                    pageTitle: 'Health Services Innovation Company',
                    pageOwner:'' ,
                    pageTemplate:'' ,
                    pageCampaign:'',
                    tags:'',
                    pageLastPublishDate:'2020-01-08T12:15:04.032-06:00',
                    pageLastPublishedBy :'admin',
                    pageLastModifiedDate:'2020-01-08T10:24:36.466-06:00',
                    pageLastModifiedBy :'katrina'
                },
               recEngine:{
                    title:'Home',
                    image:'',
                    description:''
                },
                category:{
                    siteName: window.location.hostname.replace("www.", "") ,
                    version:'3.0',

                    contentType: '',

                    contentTopic: '',
                    contentSegment: '',
                    contentInitiative: '',
                    contentProduct: '',
                    contentProductLine: '',


                    primaryCategory:'tangelo2'
                }  
           },
         event:{ }

        };
</script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: show in question minimal working code with your problem. Current code should give you all text from script - if you only don't get any error message because you forgot `" "` in `xpath("//script/text()")`

Comment: I'm trying to extract the "digitalData" dictionary.  I can parse the dictionary once I extract it from within the script tag.

Comment: If you have XHTML there is also the namespace issue...

Comment: _For some reason I'm not seeing the data expected text._ We can't do much without the expect output, or a [mcve]... That looks normal to me, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your *response* object is a response from some some *http.request*.

So to get the script content, the order of required operations is as follows:

- `txt = Response.content` - get the content of this response (a string).
- `root = etree.fromstring(txt)` - parse this string, getting the element
  tree.
- `script = root.xpath('//script')[0].text` - get the script content (for more
  detailed description see below). Probably you should also add the
  required namespace.

Note also that your code contains such a flaw that you failed to enclose
your path in quotes (either single or double).
But even if you did, the result would be a **list** of text nodes, containing
only 1 element.

My solution is simpler and more intuitive, as it:

- reads the list of matched nodes (*root.xpath('//script')*),
- takes the first of them (*[0]*) - a text node,
- retrieves the text content from it (*.text*).